# the auto increment in mysql is not working after uploading to the host

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I am working with Laravel and when I export the DB from the localhost and upload it in the host I get this error

```
ALTER TABLE `failed_jobs` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
ADD UNIQUE KEY `failed_jobs_uuid_unique` (`uuid`)
```

and I found that all auto-increment in all tables are not enabled and I have to turn in on manually, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: That's not an error, that's an SQL statement. You do not "export the DB from the localhost and upload it in the host" you run `php artisan migrate` and let the migration system do its thing.

Comment: thank u, but how to run the migration in the host?

Comment: you run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: i mean how can i run it in the live host, I do it in the terminal in localhost but what about the host?

Comment: Also use the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

That's because there is an error in your import process and some lines of your sql file not imported to server. You can reimport file and fix bugs to run all commands. also you can run parts of you sql file that contains these statements. mysql export all relationships and indexes at the end of file.